# How can I javascript decodeURI?

Tags: javascript, php

MySQL Data:

```
http%3A//www.yourname.com/path/%3FdisplayClick%23demo
(http://www.yourname.com/path/?testID#test)
```

I've used "decodeURI" but not working..

Javascipt Code:

```
$.fn.saveClicks = function() { 
$(this).bind('mousedown.clickmap', function(evt) { 
    $.post('http://www.yourname.com/path/file.php', {  
        x:evt.pageX,  
        y:evt.pageY,
        l:escape(document.location)
    }); 
}); 
};
```

For URL:

```
document.location
```

How do I clean URLs?

Comment: Why would you send the document location, isn't that available on the serverside ?

Comment: @adeneo I need to use for the remote site's address

Comment: @Ross `l:escape(document.location)` to `l:escape(encodeURIComponent(document.location))` does not work(?)

Comment: It does not change anything for you, but, please, change `document.location` to `document.location.href`. Using `document.location` (which is a Location object) as if it is a string is a legacy quirk implemented by browsers to ensure backwards compatibility with the old web.

Comment: I don't really get it, just remove the escape all together, jQuery converts the object to a string and does all the escaping for you. You're sure the request is received, cross origin ajax isn't something that is supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post('http://www.yourname.com/path/file.php', {
    …,
    l:escape(document.location)
});
```

jQuery does automatically URL-encode data you send when you pass them in as objects. No need to `escape()` anything here. That will also relieve you from having to `unescape()` the url where you actually want to use it.

So just do

```
$.post('http://www.yourname.com/path/file.php', {
    x: evt.pageX,
    y: evt.pageY,
    l: document.location.href
});
```

Comment: It's more common to use `location.href` instead of `document.location`.